# reading value from a file in batch script

Tags: file, batch-file

We can set the value of a variable (say, "upper_bound") in a batch file in the following way:

```
SET upper_bound=3
```

But is there any way to read this value '3' from a input.txt file which will just contain  value 3?

Comment: Please provide a more clear example of what will be in the input.txt file.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Windows Batch: Set Variables from Text File](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5886334/windows-batch-set-variables-from-text-file)

Comment: input.txt will just contain the value of the variable (say, 3) @Squashman

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Like this:

```
SET/P upper_bound=<input.txt
```