# Set var from text files in batch

Tags: batch-file, var

I have a question.

I would like set a var with `.txt` content.
example : `set password = contentmyfile.txt`

Thank you,

Comment: `set/P var=<"myfile.txt"`

Comment: Please show some examples of your text file.

Comment: @elzooilogico Thank you :D

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Windows Batch: Set Variables from Text File](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5886334/windows-batch-set-variables-from-text-file)